# geom_sf size argument not changing results

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, graphing

I want change the border thickness of geom_sf. From the documentation and reading questions here, I think this should be done using the size argument, however the size argument does not change anything. I can change the line type with lty and change the alpha, but not the thickness/size. Using lwd also does nothing except an error message that I should be using size.

I've read some similar questions here that suggest a similar problem with the size argument is resolved when using ggsave and changing graphics devices, however I think my problem is different as my results do not resolve with ggsave.

r-ggplot2 version=3.4.0

r-sf version=1.0.7

platform       x86_64-conda-linux-gnu
arch           x86_64
os             linux-gnu
system         x86_64, linux-gnu
version.string R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)

For the code below, the plots look exactly the same. The goal is to change the border size/thickness.

```
    library(ggplot2)
    library(sf)
    nc = sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
    ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 0.1)
    ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 1)
    ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 10)
```

Comment: Have you tried updating `sf` to 1.0.8 and `ggplot2` to 3.4.0 and changing `size` for `linewidth`? I just ran that and works perfectly

Comment: Switching to linewidth completely resolves my issue. Thank you!!

Comment: Scratch that, still having different problems. Need time to diagnose.

Comment: I had the same problem. The size parameter stopped working in code that worked properly in October (2022). Updating ggplot2 and sf and using the linewidth parameter solved this issue for me.